# How to get a SQL sequence value with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql

I would like to use a [`SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get a value from a sequence in Microsoft SQL Server. It [does not look like](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#tutorial-selecting-data) I can simply use `sqlalchemy.select()`.  I am trying to use the sqlalchemy Python package for it. I am new to sqlalchemy and I do not know whether/how I can do this?